# Hadoop Name Node format Yes by default

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

You know how you can do:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-dev
```

and the -y will automatically select Yes for "Do you want to install..."

...

How can I do this same this with:

```
bin/hadoop namenode -format -y
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work.

`echo 'Y' | hdfs namenode -format`